# Inserting NOW() into Database with CodeIgniter's Active Record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to insert current time in database using mySQL function NOW() in Codeigniter's active record. The following query won't work:

```
$data = array(
        'name' => $name ,
        'email' => $email,
        'time' => NOW()
        );
        $this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

This is because CodeIgniter’s ActiveRecord class automatically escapes the input.

The following works fine, by calling set() and passing peratmeter FALSE, so that it doesn't escape the NOW().

```
$data = array(
        'name' => $name ,
        'email' => $email,
        );
        $this->db->set('time', 'NOW()', FALSE);
        $this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

However, my question is that is there any other way than this? For example, if i can use somehow use by adding everything in the data array only? 
For example, something like:

```
$data = array(
            'name' => $name ,
            'email' => $email,
            'time' => NOW(), FALSE
            );
```

Comment: Out of the track and even scope but do you know you can get NOW() like effect using `strtotime`? For e.g. `echo date("N", strtotime('now'));` will give you today's date, refer to php.net/strtotime and php.net/date

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Unless I am greatly mistaken, the answer is, "No, there is no way."

The basic problem in situations like that is the fact that you are calling a MySQL function and you're not actually setting a value. CI escapes values so that you can do a clean insert but it does not test to see if those values happen to be calling functions like `aes_encrypt`, `md5`, or (in this case) `now()`. While in most situations this is wonderful, for those situations raw sql is the only recourse.

On a side, `date('Y-m-d');` should work as a PHP version of `NOW()` for MySQL. (It won't work for all versions of SQL though).

Comment: For simplicity I always set timestamps with date('Y-m-d H:i:s') with different ORMs etc, no need to fight against different implementations.

Comment: Personally, I always use Unix timestamps. I know that 1308124173975 will always be a long (or int, or float, or equivalent) in every language and database. I like not having to care.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm lazy so I like having human readable entries if possible. :)

Comment: @jupaju It's just a different type of laziness. I could remember how PgSQL, MySQL, Oracle, Java, PHP, and Python store dates, or I could just have everything be a gosh-darn number. And you know what? If it's a number, then it instantly translates to AS2, AS3, and JS. And when I need the actual date? Go to Chrome, Ctrl-shift-J and paste String(new Date(/*numeric timestamp*/))

Comment: I'd like to note that using date('Y-m-d H:i:s') may have an issue where the MySQL server and PHP library are using two different timezones without you being aware. For instance I had a host who had MySQL on GMT (+0h) and PHP was EST (-5h).

Answer (score 81):

I typically use triggers to handle timestamps but I think this may work.

```
$data = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'email' => $email
);

$this->db->set('time', 'NOW()', FALSE);
$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

Comment: any way to use `now() + 1 day` somehow for active records ?

Comment: Is there any way this could trigger on an empty update ?

Comment: Worked for me too, CI2.1.2 on year 2015

Comment: @AnwarHossain I am using version 3.1 and its working, there might be some other problem.

Comment: I'm using CI version 3.1.8 and it's working absolutely just fine :)

Comment: I was struggling to use sysdate in the Oracle database. this worked perfectly for me.
**$this->db->set('UPDATED_AT', 'sysdate', false);**

Answer (score 15):

aspirinemaga, just replace:

```
$this->db->set('time', 'NOW()', FALSE);
$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

for it:

```
$this->db->set('time', 'NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY', FALSE);
$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

Comment: I'd like to note that according to the docs, this is the CodeIgniter "recommended way". I'd recommend using MySQL's native NOW() rather than PHP's date('Y-m-d H:i:s') if you're on a shared host as they might be set to different timezones.

Comment: Yup, in theory you can't decide design time what your infrastructure will look like 3 years down the road. In reality, I can, often do, but shouldn't.

Answer (score 13):

This is the easy way to handle timestamp insertion

```
$data = array('created_on' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Answer (score 8):

you can load the date helper and use the codeigniter interal now() if you want to reference the users GMT time offset

it woulk look somewhat like this

```
$data = array(
'created_on' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s',now())
);
```

If you don't use the GTM master settings and let your users set their own offsets there is no advantage over using php's time() function.

Comment: date() gives php warning not to rely on systems date

Answer (score 8):

```
    $data = array(
            'name' => $name ,
            'email' => $email,
            'time' =>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            );
            $this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality. If it answers the question, consider adding a bit of text to explain how it works.

Comment: Worked for me.  Explanation might help, but it did solve my problem. 

Comment: time() is not needed, date() always return current time

Answer (score 4):

According to the source code of codeigniter, the function `set` is defined as:

```
public function set($key, $value = '', $escape = TRUE)
{
    $key = $this->_object_to_array($key);

    if ( ! is_array($key))
    {
        $key = array($key => $value);
    }

    foreach ($key as $k => $v)
    {
        if ($escape === FALSE)
        {
            $this->ar_set[$this->_protect_identifiers($k)] = $v;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->ar_set[$this->_protect_identifiers($k, FALSE, TRUE)] = $this->escape($v);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Apparently, if `$key` is an array, codeigniter will simply ignore the second parameter `$value`, but the third parameter `$escape` will still work throughout the iteration of `$key`, so in this situation, the following codes work (using the chain method):

```
$this->db->set(array(
    'name' => $name ,
    'email' => $email,
    'time' => 'NOW()'), '', FALSE)->insert('mytable');
```

However, this will unescape all the data, so you can break your data into two parts:

```
$this->db->set(array(
    'name' => $name ,
    'email' => $email))->set(array('time' => 'NOW()'), '', FALSE)->insert('mytable');
```

Answer (score 3):

putting NOW() in quotes won't work as Active Records will put escape the NOW() into a string and tries to push it into the db as a string of "NOW()"... you will need to use

```
$this->db->set('time', 'NOW()', FALSE);
```

to set it correctly.

you can always check your sql afterward with

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the date helper worked for me

```
$this->load->helper('date');
```

You can find documentation for `date_helper` [**here**](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html).

```
$data = array(
  'created' => now(),
  'modified' => now()
);

$this->db->insert('TABLENAME', $data);
```

Comment: I think its a dead link

Answer (score 0):

`$this->db->query("update table_name set ts = now() where 1=1")`
also works for current time stamp!

Answer (score 0):

run query to get now() from mysql i.e select now() as nowinmysql;

then use codeigniter to get this and put in

```
$data['created_on'] = $row->noinmyssql;
$this->db->insert($data);
```