# Using something like NOW() in a Codeigniter insert array

Tags: php, codeigniter

Because NOW() is a MySQL method I cannot seem to get it to work in the below array. What is a function I can use in PHP which will do the same thing as the NOW() method.

```
$data = array('node1id' => $leader_id,
              'node2id' => $idgen,
              'friendsSince' => NOW(),
$this->db->insert('users', $data);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting NOW() into Database with CodeIgniter's Active Record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354315/inserting-now-into-database-with-codeigniters-active-record)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the codeigniter date helper and keep the same notation:

```
$this->load->helper('date');

$data = array('node1id' => $leader_id,
          'node2id' => $idgen,
          'friendsSince' => now(),
$this->db->insert('users', $data);
```

More info on date helper in CI docs here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html

Comment: the mysql function NOW() returns the current date and time suitable for the timestamp or datetime field. The now() function from codeigniters date helper returns the time in unix timestamp. This answer would not work if your field is DATETIME or TIMESTAMP. The other two answers would work, Kamrul's answer being the best one.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `date("Y-m-d");` or `date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` depending on what you need `DATE` vs `DATETIME`

Comment: ^ I'm Claudrian and I support this message! Do it manually, more power to you.

Comment: maybe, you would need to do it this way:

date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($time-string));

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$this->db->set('node1id', $leader_id);  
$this->db->set('node2id', $idgen);
$this->db->set('friendsSince', 'NOW()', FALSE); 

$this->db->insert('users');
```

Whenever use a MySQL function, use FALSE as the third parameter.