# MySQL Functions in Codeigniter Data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, insert

Using codeigniter I'm trying to insert a row into my database, but I want the data in the row to be generated by MySQL. What is the proper way of doing it?

```
$data['my_id'] = 'UUID()';
$db->insert('my_table',$data);
```

Obviously the above won't work, but how can I make it function?

EDIT:
Theoretically this is what the above should produce:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (my_id) VALUES (UUID());
```

Naturally my actually query isn't that simple, but that should get the point across.

Comment: you are saying you will retrieve data from Mysql using SQL functions and then you want to insert it in the MySQl again the same data.....am i right if not please correct me.....

Comment: No, I'm not grabbing any data from MySQL. I just want to make 1 call to the server. (i'll update my details to give a little more detail as to what I mean)

Comment: @GBD UUID() is a MySQL function that produces a unique identifier http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

Comment: `$this->db->set('my_id', 'UUID()', FALSE);` then do the insert.

Comment: @itachi What if I had more data as well? Say $data['my_amount'] = '$12'; ? (variable number of items in the data array)... Would I have to do a set for each one or can I pass in my array of data and then do a second call for the 'my_id' one?

Comment: 1) construct the array 2)`$this->db->set('my_id', 'UUID()', FALSE);` 3) `$db->insert('my_table',$data);` You can use `set` only when you need it.

Comment: [**this link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354315/inserting-now-into-database-with-codeigniters-active-record) should clear it.

Comment: @itachi Awesome! Thanks =) Did you want to put the answer below so I can accept it? =D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use `$this->db->set('my_id', 'UUID()', FALSE);`

For passing mltiple params,

```
$data = array(.....) //add the params.
$this->db->set('my_id', 'UUID()', FALSE);
$this->db->insert('my_table',$data);
```

Comment: This works great. You can skip the `$data` var completely if you're just updating one field.