# Proper way to use datetime in Codeigniter queries

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I wonder if there is some type of common method that would help me write query with date/time field in it. For example: I am developing a very small project utilizing MySQL database. However, my client is considering switching to his existing SQL server.

Example (`datetime` column):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(contract_date, '%d.%m.%Y') FROM `employees`
```

Question: Can query below become usable in SQL in case I replace database driver (currently) `mysqli` to `sqlsrv`?

I understand I can use some type of config variable for date format... Would it be the best way? Is there something that Codeigniter 3 has in place?

- feel free to use your own query sample

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20943216/2488916