# Insert Current DateTime in Codeigniter 3.0.6

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

I'm trying to store user signup date and time using codeigniter 3.0.6 and using

```
NOW()
```

as

```
 $this->db->set('user_nicename', $nameVar);
   $this->db->set('user_login', $emailVar);
   $this->db->set('user_pass', $passwordVar);
   $this->db->set('user_registered', 'NOW()');
   $this->db->insert('doc_users');
```

but it is not storing date time in database

[see database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9OAg.png)

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354315/inserting-now-into-database-with-codeigniters-active-record

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this works for me in Codeigniter 3.0.6

```
$this->db->set('user_registered', 'NOW()', FALSE);
```

Answer (score 15):

use `date()` like this

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); # output 2015-12-22 16:41:25
```

---

**Final Code is**

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi'); # add your city to set local time zone
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$this->db->set('user_nicename', $nameVar);
$this->db->set('user_login', $emailVar);
$this->db->set('user_pass', $passwordVar);
$this->db->set('user_registered', $now);
$this->db->insert('doc_users');
```

Comment: use `date_default_timezone_set`

Comment: returning 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: set your database field to `DATETIME`

Comment: i need globally time not for only one country

Comment: UTC time or your local time?/

Comment: UTC is one not depends on each and other

Comment: @KashifLatif try with `gmdate`

Comment: You have to store all in 1 format. Not separate formats !!

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');` this code is working fine for only pakistan, but i need a globally solution

Comment: what about this `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98724/discussion-between-kashif-latif-and-abdulla).

Answer (score 3):

try this

first load date helper

To follow ci structure you have to use mdate() function  otherwise you can also use date function

```
$this->db->set('user_nicename', $nameVar);
$this->db->set('user_login', $emailVar);
$this->db->set('user_pass', $passwordVar);
$this->db->set('user_registered', mdate("%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s"));
$this->db->insert('doc_users');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using load the date helper.

```
mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now());
```

There is no need to use multiple sets you could simply put it in a array.

```
$data = array(
   'user_nicename' => $nameVar,
   'user_login' => $emailVar,
   'user_pass' => $passwordVar,
   'user_registered' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now())
);

$this->db->set($data);
$this->db->insert('doc_users');
```

Also make sure your user_registered database type is DATETIME

To set your current date_time_zone

Go to the config.php and add the code below

Example: `date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Auckland');`

For your time zone you can find list here http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = [
    'type'=>$this->input->post('txttype')
    //for getting input value of form
];

$this->db->set('column_name', 'NOW()', FALSE);

$this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can make a DB query to get current DB date/time:

```
$this->db->select('NOW() as db_date')->get()->row()->db_date
```

Answer (score 0):

> In Codeigniter, you have to load date helper as
>   `$this->load->helper('date');`. than after you have to define city for
>   timezone as `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');`.than after
>   you can set your time zone according your requirnment.

```
$this->load->helper('date'); // load Helper for Date 

date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
echo $date=gmdate("F j, Y").'<br>'; // ie. May 23, 2018

if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
{
  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); // Specify your time zone according to your city
}

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); // Defined City For Timezone
$currentDate =time();
$datestring = '%Y-%m-%d - %h:%i %a';
$time = time();
$better_date= mdate($datestring, $time).'<br>'; //  i.e : 2018-05-23 - 09:52 am | For AM | PM result
$c_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s").'<br>'; // 2018-05-23 09:52:36 | For Seconds Result

// Insert Date and Time to the Database

$data=array(
  'name'    =>'Rudra',
  'email' =>'test@me.com',
  'city'    =>'Kolakata',
  'data_time_on'=>$c_date
);

$this->db->insert('tableName',$data);
```